# Decompose incoming JSON to Objects by fields with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-rest

I need to decompose my incoming JSON by fields in me REST Controller with Spring Boot.

My request body:

```json
{
  "text": "my text",
  "myEnum": "VALUE1"
}
```

And my controller:

```java
@PatchMapping("/{id}")
Object updateEntity(@PathVariable Long id, String text, MyEnum myEnum) {
    /* ... */
}
```

`@RequestParam` doesn't work because it's just for query string params, `@RequestBody` doesn't work too because it handle whole body. But I need decompose incoming body by fields and inject into controller. I know what I can use `Map <String, String>` for this, but I would like validate my incoming fields, and I have the fields with difference types. And I don't want to create one class by incoming body for each controller.

Answer (score 1):

If I haven't misunderstood your requirement, the usual way to deal with incoming JSON is to define a class that reflects your expected input, and make that the controller method parameter annotated as RequestBody.

Spring Boot, by default, uses Jackson to deserialize to your class, and so if you use matching property names then you won't need any special annotations or setup. I think enums will be handled by default, as are other types (though you may need to provide some guidance for strings representing dates or timestamps). Any bad value will fail deserialisation, which I think you can handle in ControllerAdvice (though you'll want to double check that)

Comment: Yes I know but I don't want to create one class by Incoming body for each controller

Comment: Oh I understand, not sure if that's possible without looking up documentation, but suspect that separate classes would be as simple as defining a decomposed list of properties in each controller method anyway. If you use Lombok (or Kotlin) then you wouldn't need all the boilerplate code that is a downside of these small data holder classes.

Comment: Yes I know, I can use java Records for this too, but maybe other way exists.

Comment: Oh of course - I'm stuck with Java 8 still! Hope someone comes back with a solution for decomposition. I'll have a look around if I get a chance later, but at work now.